# Как правильно подключить вебсокет?

Tags: python, websocket

`test.py`

```
from socket import create_connection
from time import time as timestamp

class Client():
    def __init__(self, email, password)
        result = requests.post("https://service.narvii.com/api/v1/g/s/auth/login", data=json.dumps(
                              {"email": email, "secret": "0 " + password, "deviceID": "015051B67B8D59D0A86E0F4A78F47367B749357048DD5F23DF275F05016B74605AAB0D7A6127287D9C",
                               "clientType": 100, "action": "normal", "timestamp": (int(timestamp() * 1000))}), 
                                headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}).json())
        self.sid = result["sid"]

    def listen(self):
        ws = create_connection(("wss://ws1.narvii.comsignbody=015051B67B8D59D0A86E0F4A78F47367B749357048DD5F23DF275F05016B74605AAB0D7A6127287D9C%7C" + str((int(timestamp() * 1000))) + "&sid=" + self.sid))
        return ws
```

`bot.py`

```
from lib.test import Client

client = Client(<email>, <password>)

while True:
    print(client.listen())
```

Этот вебсокет присылает информацию о новых сообщениях со всех чатов в которых состоит авторизованный пользователь. Проблема в том, что он часто пропускает сообщения. Я хочу написать бота для этого приложения, и чтобы минимизировать нагрузку, мне нужно его подключить. Читал в интернете о разных способах это сделать, но какой стоит выбрать так и не понял. Как лучше и правильней его подключить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант вы постоянно создаете новые соединение `create_connection` хотя можно было бы работать в одном что несколько снизит нагрузку. Без ограничения по времени в бесконечном цикле это смахивает на DDos.

Пропуск сообщений скорее всего из за того что сервер шлет данные в сокет а Вы уже открыли новый и ждете данные там. Вместо обновления данных в текущем. Хотя это зависит от того как сервер хранит и отсылает данные.

Простой пример для клиента:

```py
from socket import create_connection
ws = socket.create_connection(("127.0.0.1", 8001))
while True:
    ws.send(b"CLIENT\n")
    res = ws.recv(1024)
    print(res)
```

Упрощенная модель сервера заглушки

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(("", 8001))
sock.listen(5)
client, addr = sock.accept()
while True:
    result = client.recv(1024)
    print("Message: ", result.decode("utf-8"))
    client.send(b"TEST MSG!") 
client.close()
```

Для вашего случая в `test.py` добавил бы метод:

```py
def start_msg(self):
    ws = сreate_connection(("wss://ws1.narvii.comsignbody=015051B67B8D59D0A86E0F4A78F47367B749357048DD5F23DF275F05016B74605AAB0D7A6127287D9C%7C" + str((int(timestamp() * 1000))) + "&sid=" + self.sid))
    while True:
        ws.send(b"CLIENT\n")
        res = ws.recv(1024)
        print(res)
```

А в `bot.py`(а нужен ли он..):

```py
from lib.test import Client

client = Client(<email>, <password>)
client.start_msg()
```

Единственное вызывают немного сомнения параметры передаваемые в сreate_connection но это это уже вам отлаживать.

Comment: Вроде приблизительно понял как это работает, но как это использовать конкретно в моем случае, и как сделать чтобы получать от вебсокета инфу?